# spark read orc with specific columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a orc file, when read with below option it reads all the columns .

```
val df= spark.read.orc("/some/path/")

df.printSChema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- all: string (nullable = true)
 |-- next: string (nullable = true)
 |-- action: string (nullable = true)
```

but I want to read only two columns from that file , is there any way to read only two columns (id,name) while loading orc file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to read only two columns (id,name) while loading orc file ?

Yes, all you need is subsequent select. Spark will take care of the rest for you:

```
val df = spark.read.orc("/some/path/").select("id", "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark has lazy execution model. So you can do any data transformation in you code without immediate real effect. Only after [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) call Spark start to doing job. And Spark are smart enough not to do extra work.
So you can write like this:

```
val inDF: DataFrame = spark.read.orc("/some/path/")   

import spark.implicits._
val filteredDF: DataFrame = inDF.select($"id", $"name")

// any additional transformations  

// real work starts after this action 
val result: Array[Row] = filteredDF.collect()
```